# Trying to layout divs in CSS like table

Tags: html, css-tables

I am trying to adhere to best practices, and **not** use a table, but I'm trying to setup a fixed width table layout using divs.

Table: 768px wide 1024px tall
Row 1: 56px high
  Cell 1: 56px wide  Cell 2: 600px wide  Cell 3: 112px wide
Row 2: 912 high
  Cell 1: 56px wide  Cell 2: 600px wide  Cell 3: 112px wide
Row 3: 56px high
  Cell 1: 56px wide  Cell 2: 600px wide  Cell 3: 112px wide

I get the first row set up in CSS correctly:

```
section { display: table; width: 768px;}
div { display: table-cell; height:56px; border: 1px solid #000;} /* height:56px; */
#top_gutter { width:56px; height:56px; }
#title { width:600px; height:56px; }
#top_margin { width:112px; height:56px; }
```

but subsequent rows do not display correctly.  I've tried many different ways, but I'm not seeing what I'm doing incorrectly.  I've tried setting up `<section2>` and `<div2>`, but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `float` instead of `display`: http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option for creating a customizable table using `div`s

```css
.cell {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example you can apply your own constraints on this structure, for example if you want to set 768px for the whole table width you can accomplish it by:

```
.table {
    width: 768px;
}
```

Or setting height 40px for odd rows:

```
.row:nth-child(2n+1) {
    height: 40px;
}
```